# Why does changing initialization vector in AES-256 mean I can bypass authentication?

Tags: aes

Let's say I am setting a cookie in Node JS using AES-256, a 5 random character string as the plain text and any old string as the key.

```
 var cipher = aes256.encrypt(key, plain);
```

I then set a cookie with something like this:

```
{"user":"GUEST","plain":"{THE_PLAIN_TEXT}","cipher":"{THE_CIPHER}"}
```

Now, to decrypt it, my Node JS function does the following:

```
var plain = aes256.decrypt(key, cipher);
```

I then do a check to say if `plain` and `cipher` are the same, log the user in.

Now, the problem is that if I amend the cookie to change the user to `ADMIN` or any other known user, leave `plain` as blank and set `cipher` to any 21 byte string, it will log me in automatically.

Why does setting the string to this length log me in automatically? I know it's something to do with the initialization vector but how can this be explained in simple terms?

Comment: You just edited away most of your question?

Comment: Rolled it back to the initial version of the question, as the question with the info missing did not make sense. Changing questions is allowed, but changing it too drastically is not, especially if it has already been answered. Edits should improve the question.

Answer (score 5):

Let's suppose `aes256.encrypt` means AES-256 in CBC mode, and let's suppose the entire message is a single block long.  The ciphertext $C$ is related to the key $k$, plaintext $P$, and initialization vector $I$ by $$C = \operatorname{AES256}_k(P \oplus I),$$ where $\oplus$ means xor.

What happens if I replace $I$ by $I' \ne I$?  If, given $C$ and $P$ and $I$ but not $k$, I want to find the $C'$ for some plaintext $P' \ne P$, how can I do that?

**Instead of using *encryption*, you should use *authentication*.**  Instead of sending the plaintext $P$ and the ciphertext $C = E_k(P)$ for some cipher $E_k$, send the plaintext $P$ and an authenticator tag $T = M_k(P)$ for some authenticator $M_k$.  Authenticators are designed to do what you're trying to do.

In this context, you are practically guaranteed to have HMAC-SHA256 readily at your fingertips as such an authenticator $M_k$.  Your obligation is to pick $k$ uniformly at random from all 256-bit strings.  In return, HMAC-SHA256 guarantees that the adversary's probability of guessing the authentication tag for a message $P$ never before seen is negligible.

Make sure that when you act on an authenticated plaintext, the only *parts* of the plaintext you act on are the parts that were actually covered by the authentication tag.  And make sure that the sender and receiver agree *up front* that they are using HMAC-SHA256, so that an adversary can't replace the algorithm choice in a message in transit and cause the receiver to accept an authentication tag from a weak or incomparable algorithm.